# Upload half-million rows into SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, performance, ado.net

Hi guys I need your advice

I need to upload about half-million rows from a xml file into a SqlServer table periodically. I could use SqlBulkCopy but there is some extra logic. I need to track changes in the xml files and copy that changes into another table.  What is the best way to do it?  I dont't want to use Entity Framework or LinqToSql because I want to set table names in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Use BulkCopy.

- [Bulk Copy Operations in SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a.aspx)
- [Sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y8tb169.aspx)

Comment: +1 this was my answer upon reading the title of the question!

Comment: Could you explain please how to implement the tracking changes logic using SqlBulkCopy. I didn't find any the tracking changes logic in the example that you linked. First of all I need to grab the xml file and select some nodes from the xml file after that I need to upload these nodes into SqlServer. If there is some changes I need to copy rows with changes into a separate table.

Comment: @G2: If you know exact rows to insert, you can create the xml file with changes (inserts). You can create the xml file in C#/VB.NET/... or you can select the inserted rows as xml.